# Are these settings correct for sending mail through Rails/Gmail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail, email

I spend a good deal of time building an email system for my Rails app that uses Gmail to send bulk mail to a list of opt-in users.  I realize a shortcomming of using Google Apps for my mail, namely a rate limit on the number of emails it will send out (i believe 500).  Anyway, I have reached out to my users to see how many have received the email, and a lot of them have not, though some have.  The list I tried sending to was about 540 users, so I would have expected more "yes, got it," then "nope, still waiting" responses.

I have two questions:

1. Do these settings look correct for outgoing bulk mailing through Gmail?  Again, using google apps to manage my domain and i know some people (including myself) have received the mailer.  This is in a mail.rb initializer in my app.

   ```
   ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :sendmail
   ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
     :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
     :port => 25,
     :domain => "mydomain.com",
     :authentication => :login,
     :user_name => "no-reply@mydomain.com",
     :password => "mypass"
   }
   ```
2. Is there any way I can test if the mail was delivered, or at least attempted to be delivered?  I can't tell where in the list the mailer stops mailing!  The way I generate the list is through a query which then passes the user info to a mailer worker which sends the emails out via Starling/Workling.  Any advice here would be useful.  Happy to post code, but want to make sure the method I'm using is sound.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I just went into my mailq on the production server where the emails are sent and saw two emails in the queue that were not sent due to bad email address formats.  Does anyone know if mail will continue to send in spite of having email in the queue still?

Comment: it should - those are just set to 'retry', usually for around 2 days or so before they are deleted and/maybe you would get a bounce back to your sending address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmail requires TLS (a form of SSL, usually setting useSSL to true will work) on the outbound smtp server with port 587, not port 25.  Also, I have never seen the need to set a domain on a Gmail apps account and setting up programmatic email sends. (.NET and PHP).

Answer (score 1):

According to this http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287 you should use secured connection, either TLS or SSL.